# Is there any open source firmware or OS for IP camera like openwrt for routers

Tags: smart-home, digital-cameras, open-source

Is there any open source firmware or OS for IP cameras like [OpenWrt](https://openwrt.org/) for routers.

I need an OS or a firmware for IP cameras in order to communicate with our cloud service easily. I have some experience with OpenWrt that's why I'm thinking in that way.

My target is to get an HTTP call (minimum GET call ) from the IP camera. Is there any IP camera which are using opensource firmware?

Comment: What does "My target is to get an HTTP call (minimum GET call ) from the IP camera" even mean??  Do you wish to make an HTTP request *to* the camera's computer, or do you wish the camera's computer to make a request to something else?  And what should that request accomplish? Beyond that, this remains a list question not fitting the Stack Exchange mission, but as previously suggested there are OpenWRT based implementations and webcam demos for OpenWRT platforms like the MT7688, typically using a USB camera.  No doubt there exist demos for the Raspberry Pi as well.

Comment: 1) Click OpenWRT link in the question 2) Type "camera" in the search box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that [OpenIPC](https://github.com/OpenIPC) firmware is exactly like OpenWrt for IP cameras.

Answer (score 5):

I am looking for the same thing and found your request here in my Google search. There are a ton of opensource cameras out there. Something high end (3D stereo vision for starters): https://www.elphel.com/ open hardware and free software. I am not associated with this company, they happen to be local and I've  known the founder for years.

Comment: He searches something other: he buys proprietary IP cam product and flashes Open Source firmware. Most Open Source hardware is not competitive to proprietary products.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with openWRT with some models, though is not offically supported and not fully functional, example:
https://blog.tho.ms/hacks/2016/08/28/openwrt-on-logilink-wc0030a.html
That camera uses a popular soic used in many similar models

Comment: Welcome to Internet of Things! While the link may theoretically answer the question, [it would be better](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.  Please [edit] to include more details... answer without sufficient detail are subject to removal.  Thanks!